# Django Sendgrid Heroku setup

Tags: django, heroku, sendgrid, django-email

I use a Django / Sendgrid / Heroku setup which was working well but it stopped with no apparent reason.

my django settings:

```py
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.sendgrid.net"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="..."
EMAIL_HOST_USER="..."
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

with this settings, if I send simple emails with the django library...

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail 
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    from_email_address,
    [to_email_address],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

I get this error

```
--> SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

I can still send emails using the sendgrid python library

```py
import sendgrid 
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey)
sg.send(data)
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the current version of your sendgrid package?

Comment: 6.3.1 but I don't use the sendgrid package in production, I just try to test if it was related to my sendgrid price plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out:
Sendgrid dynamically provides a password through the `SENDGRID_PASSWORD` Heroku environment variable. However the variable used for the email settings is `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` which was not updated after our password changed.

Be sure that both variables are identical